# Proof by induction for $\left(1−\frac14\right)\cdot\left(1−\frac19\right)\cdots\left(1−\frac1{n^2}\right)$ for all natural numbers $n$ with $n \ge 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, products, pattern-recognition

Make a conjecture about a formula for the product: $\left(1−\frac14\right)\cdot\left(1−\frac19\right)\cdot\cdots\cdot\left(1−\frac1{n^2}\right)$ for all natural numbers $n$ with $n \ge 2$. Then, state a theorem about the formula and use mathematical induction to prove your theorem. Any help appreciated!

I don't know what the conjecture is, thats what I need help with. All I found was the result is always between 0 and 1. I don't know if there should be something more to that or not.

Comment: Did you try computing the first few products of this form? What results did you get? What is your conjecture?

Comment: I don't know what the conjecture is, thats what I need help with. All I found was the result is always between 0 and 1. I don't know if there should be something more to that or not.

Comment: Yeah, it should be a *lot* more. Write out the first four terms and see what they are.

Comment: Well for the first four terms I get a result of .75, .8889, .9375, and .96 which multiplied together is .6. I don't know what to do from there.

Comment: Write these as fractions and simplify.

Comment: As fractions it is 3/4 * 8/9 * 15/16 * 24/25 = 3/5

Comment: @HeathLawrence By the way, the sequence of terms you should be looking for is $$\left(1−\frac14\right),\,\,\,\left(1−\frac14\right)\cdot\left(1−\frac19\right),\,\,\,\left(1−\frac14\right)\cdot\left(1−\frac19\right)\cdot\left(1−\frac1{16}\right), \dots$$ Right now, it looks like you are looking at $$\left(1−\frac14\right),\,\,\,\left(1−\frac19\right),\,\,\,\left(1−\frac1{16}\right),\dots$$user296602 suggested to write out _that_ sequence and hope to spot a pattern

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. Why is the sequence of terms have (1-1/4) repeated, then in the next sequence it isn't repeated? I though it would just be continuous to whatever n is so (1-1/4) * (1-1/9) and so on until whatever n is.

Comment: @HeathLawrence There is not enough space to write it in the comments, so I have posted it in the answers. Let me know if it makes sense, and how you get on

Comment: See also [Proving $\prod_{i=2}^{i=n} \left(1-\frac{1}{i^2}\right) = \frac{n+1}{2n}$ by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1464207) or [Simplifying the product $\prod\limits_{k=2}^n \left(1-\frac1{k^2}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1314371)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I am not sure if this is a duplicate - it seems OP's main problem was forming the induction hypothesis, rather than proving it, no?

Comment: @JohnDoe Perhaps. (To be honest the OP did not say much what his problem actually is.) IIRC when I came here the question already had two close votes as off-topic/missing context. (I guess that you chose this reason in your close vote.) From the two possible outcomes (closure as off-topic/closure as duplicate) I thought that duplicate might be more useful choice, since it at least points the OP (and other users seeing this post) to other questions about the same problem. But very likely there is no much difference between the two possibilities.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, that's right, I had chosen off topic. I should have retracted that when OP was responsive in the comments I suppose, but oh well. And yes, I agree - the second link in particular actually has a nice proof that is different to induction.

Comment: @HeathLawrence As you can see from the above comments, some users voted to close your question with the close reason [missing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/context/info) - similar as you saw in [some of your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2739291/prove-for-every-natural-number-n-with-n-≥-7-that-frac2n−18n2−8n). It might help if you edit your question a bit. (I have at least included what you mentioned in your first comment.)

Comment: @JohnDoe It seems after your reopen vote (I suppose it was from you judging by the above comment) the question went to [reopen votes review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/996538), but the end result was to leave the question closed.

Answer (score 1):

The terms in your sequence are:

$n={2}$: term is $\left(1-\frac1{4}\right)$

$n={3}$: term is $\left(1-\frac1{4}\right)\times\left(1-\frac1{9}\right)$

$n={4}$: term is $\left(1-\frac1{4}\right)\times\left(1-\frac1{9}\right)\times\left(1-\frac1{16}\right)$

$n={5}$: term is $\left(1-\frac1{4}\right)\times\left(1-\frac1{9}\right)\times\left(1-\frac1{16}\right)\times\left(1-\frac1{25}\right)$

$\cdots$

(**Edit:** writing a proper answer now that OP has figured it out)

The numbers you got, when written as fractions are: $$\left\{\frac34,\,\,\frac23,\,\,\frac58,\,\,\frac35,\cdots\right\}=\left\{\frac34,\,\,\frac46,\,\,\frac58,\,\,\frac6{10},\cdots\right\}$$Here, the numerator clearly has nth term of $n+1$, and the denominator has $2n$ as the nth term. So we conjecture that the general term is $$\frac{n+1}{2n}$$ What is left is to prove this by induction.

Comment: well I tried taking the result of each n term so for n = 2 its .75, then n=3 it is .667, then n = 4 is .625, n=5 is .6. The pattern I see which I guess is obvious is that the answer continues to get smaller as n gets larger. I don't see any other patterns, which i'm sure my pattern doesn't help at all :(

Comment: Ok, that is good. The numbers you got, when written as fractions are: $$\frac34,\,\,\frac23,\,\,\frac58,\,\,\frac35$$Now i'll give you a hint - instead of writing them like that, i will write them like this: $$\frac34,\,\,\frac46,\,\,\frac58,\,\,\frac6{10}$$Do you see what is happening for each term? Do you see a pattern in the numerators? And the denominators?

Comment: Wow ok yes I see the pattern in the answers. So for whatever n is, the result will be (n+1) / (2n). So then from there would my conjecture be that if n is a natural number greater than 2, then (1−1/4)⋅(1−1/9)⋅⋯⋅(1−1/n^2) = (n+1) / (2n) and from there just do normal mathematical induction?

Comment: @HeathLawrence sorry for the late reply, but yes, thats it!

Comment: Thank you so much!